# Eexecute groovy code in soapui cucumber project

Tags: groovy, junit, cucumber, soapui

I am trying to run existing SoapUI tests with Cucumber for a customer.
I have use this example https://www.soapui.org/docs/test-automation/junit/junit-integration/

The test execution in Cucumber works fine for SoapUI test cases with REST Requests.

But my customer also uses groovy code in a few test cases. All test cases with groovy code shows in result (test runner) an error.

**My question:** Is it possible to execute groovy code via Cucumber/JUnit?

I'm not sure in the documentation i haven't found anything about it.

This is my groovy code:

```
def ec00Configuration = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Configuration")
def response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(context.expand( '${Request#Response}' )).message
def dealerId = response.find{it.name == ec00Configuration.getPropertyValue("dealerName")}?.id
log.info "Id of dealer is : ${dealerId}"
// move to property for demo!
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("dealerId",dealerId)
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I use an assert for checking the status:
`assertEquals(TestRunner.Status.FINISHED, testRunner.getStatus());`

This return FAILED:
```java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :FINISHED
Actual   :FAILED```

The test case with groovy code is rinnung successfully in SoapUI.

Comment: find the error message why groovy step is failing then it'll be possible to help. probably you just need to add groovy dependencies into your project if you are running from java.

Comment: I have add groovy dependencies to my pow. It has no impact on the behavior of the test.

Comment: I tested another case ... if a test step as a "Properties" is available in the SoapUI test case, then the test in Cucumber will also fail. It's a shame it doesn't work :(